# Дёрганая работа аккордиона

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток.
Возник следующий вопрос:
На странице есть форма для заполнения, которую, если она пуста, необходимо свернуть (как бы аккордеоном, нам остается видна только стрелочка показывающая на разворот вниз). При скрытии и открытии использую функции `slideDown` и `slideUp`. Но почему-то анимация получается порой весьма дерганной и ступенчатой. Вот пример кода:

```js
$("#arrow").click(function() {
  if ($("[data-status]").attr('data-status') == "true") {
    $("[data-status]").attr('data-status', false);
    $(".my-form").slideUp(400, function() {
      $("[data-status]").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
    });
  } else {
    $("[data-status]").attr('data-status', true);
    $(".my-form").slideDown(400, function() {
      $("[data-status]").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-up");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.my-form {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-top: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="span12">
    <i class="icon-chevron-up" data-status="true" id="arrow"></i>
  </div>
  <form action="adress" id="form" method="get">
    <div class="span12 my-form" style="display: block;">
      ......
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Высота формы не оговорена, т.к. она адаптивна.
Используется `bootstrap` (насколько могу судить по имеющимся функциям примерно 2) и `jquery 2.0.3`.

Подскажите в какую сторону можно копать, заранее спасибо.

P.S. Ссылка на JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7xpdwdnv/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7xpdwdnv/ - вот копия вашего кода, все работает плавно. Вероятно, проблема не собственно в коде, а либо в стилях страницы, либо в самой форме, либо в каком-то доп. скрипте, который что-то пытается сделать с формой.

Comment: Спасибо большое, что уделили время. Фигня какая-то если честно(..единственное на, что могу грешить так это на то, что вниз сдвигается достаточно большая страница

Comment: Проверил. Всё работает плавно. А страница, где этот код используется сильно перегружена? А точно дело не в машине, на которой тестируете? ПРобовали с других устройств?

Comment: сам спойлер содержит до 6 полей ввода и где-то 5-10 радиобаттонов или чекбоксов. а контент под спойлером в виде таблицы на 20 записей. вроде не сильно перегружен. Возможно вопрос и в машине.. но вроде ничего экстроординарного не грузит её...